# How can I add two different slugs on two models in two different apps in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, django-class-based-views, slug

I trying to add slugs to my service page and my project page, but whenever I try to run my project page I get the Page not found (404)
No service found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/
Raised by:  pages.views.<class 'pages.views.ServiceDetail'>

Here's my class-based code

## models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
alt = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
icon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = RichTextField()
shortdesc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('service_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class Project(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
alt = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
client = models.CharField(max_length=50)
launched = models.CharField(max_length=50)
demands = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = RichTextField()
shortdesc = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
video_link = models.URLField(max_length=100)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

## urls.py

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.ServiceDetail.as_view(), name='service_detail'),

path('project/<slug:slug>/', views.ProjectDetail.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
```

## views.py

```
def project(request):
return render(request, 'project/project.html')

class ProjectDetail (generic.DetailView):
model = Project
template_name = 'project/project_detail.html'

def service(request):
return render(request, 'pages/service.html')

class ServiceDetail (generic.DetailView):
model = Service
template_name = 'pages/service_detail.html'
```

how can I re-route so that my project page can work out? any help would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

The error message has the following reason:

1. you make a call to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/"
2. your path statement is routing it to 'pages.views.ServiceDetail' - with url parameter slug="project"

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.ServiceDetail.as_view(),
```

3. Inheritance of ServiceDetail -> DetailView -> BaseDetailView -> SingleObjectMixin   (among others..)
4. as you make a GET request, method get() in BaseDetailView is called:

```
  def get(...)
     self.object = self.get_object()
```

5. method get_object() in SingleObjectMixin

```
        try:
            # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
            obj = queryset.get()
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                          {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
```

6. queryset.get()  tries to find an item with slug="project" which does not exist in database and handles the resulting excpetin whit the 404 response that you get as error message

So to avoid that the call to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/" is going to be routed by

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.ServiceDetail.as_view().....
```

you need to change the order of paths:

```
path('project/<slug:slug> ....
path('<slug:slug> ....
```

and make a call like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/your_project_slug"

With you current order, 'project' is interpreted as slug, because paths are matched one after the other.

Comment: i Am still getting the same error with this

Comment: please update your question with your current files and the complete error message

Comment: I updated the answer with a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your url path in urls.py is pointing to path('project/slug:slug/',...), however you are requesting a page without the /slug:slug/ part being passed http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/  (slug part missing). Request http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/slug-name (replace slug-name with a valid slug) and see if it works.

Also see Razensteins answer